# Moving washer machine 7 feet from trap

Tags: plumbing, washing-machine

Can I still use existing drain, p trap & vent that's in place by extending drain pipe from new location to existing trap?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on 1) how high your washing machine pump can eject water and 2) how high your existing drain already is. You have to be especially cautious with upright (non-high efficiency) washers as they dump a lot of water very quickly with each cycle and this can overwhelm a slow drain even if it meets code.

In the worst case scenario, you’ll need a gray water pump to help pump the wastewater out to the drain location. Any plumber should be able to help you with that.

Note that your dryer will also have a maximum distance, height, and number of air ducting bends that its vent motor can handle.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I do have h.e. LG washer an dryer. Dryer venting will be no issue at all, going straight out wall with it.  I guess my main concern as you mentioned is water draining fast enough.  Do you think even though it's only 7 ft I would still need to add gray water pump? Thanks!

Comment: It’s impossible for random internet strangers to know. If it drains well now and you have a high efficiency washer or a good standpipe setup (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standpipe_(plumbing)) you might be ok but your drain could always narrow with lint in the future and you could have a problem. I’d get some bids from local plumbers.